# Is there a way to retrieve all items without an attribute in DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

So I recently added a Time To Live attribute to my DynamoDB table (850 million records). I'm trying to write a script to backfill the Time To Live attribute in my table.

I'm want to retrieve all the items in this the table without the Time To Live attribute set, so I can backfill these items with the Time To Live using UpdateItem.

Is there a way to do this in DynamoDB?

Answer (score 1):

If your database is small, a simple `scan` will work:

```
var params = {
    TableName: "<YOUR TABLE NAME>",
    FilterExpression: "attribute_not_exists(time_to_live)"
};

var results = dynamodb.scan(params);

// update records here
```

If your DB is large, you may want to consider the [more thoughtful approach outlined by AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/backfilling-an-amazon-dynamodb-time-to-live-ttl-attribute-with-amazon-emr/), which includes using AWS EMR to backfill data in DynamoDB.  Bonus, the linked article discusses backfilling time to live attributes in DynamoDB!

Comment: My DB is large (850 mil items), so would this mean I would have to scan multiple times?

Comment: If your DB is that large, I'd suggest following the approach outlined in the AWS blog post.  You don't want to pay to read 850mm items with scan!